# Laravel - How to get Entrust Roles of a specific user

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a small work with Laravel and using **Zizaco Entrust**.

While logged in as Administrator I want to see all **Roles** of a specific user.

I'v searched for a while but didn't find any clue...
How can I do it using **Entrust** or shall I use SQL queries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your User class add

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role','assigned_roles');
}
```

Then you can get all roles for a specific user

```
$user = User::with('roles')->find(1);
$roles = $user->roles;
```

Comment: `$roles = $user->roles;` works indeed but returns all roles in array. When I do `$roles = $user->roles[0]->name;` I can get specific rows like name and created_at. But I need to loop this (So not with `[0]`) for all the roles... How should I do this (in the view)?

Comment: use `foreach` to loop over a collection, in the view use [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade) syntax, something like this `@foreach ($user->roles as $role) {{ $role->name }} @endforeach`

Comment: Was just about to say that I tried it before and didn't work, but now it does.. Must have been a typo :/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Zizaco\Entrust you don't need new roles method in User model. Roles method already exist in EntrustUserTrait class. You only need this line inside User class:

```
use EntrustUserTrait;
```

like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use EntrustUserTrait; // add this trait to your user model
            .....
}
```

In your UsersController you can select users with their roles (index method):

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    protected $users;

public function __construct(User $users)
{
    $this->users = $users;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $users = $this->users->with('roles')->paginate(25);
    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

In your blade loop $user->roles inside $users loop because $user->roles are collection even if user have only one role.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @foreach($user->roles as $role)
        {{ $role->display_name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```