# Entrust not finding user's roles

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following in my controller method that returns JSON to my view:

```
    public function RolesForUser()
    {
        $userid = Input::get('userid');

        $assigned = DB::table('assigned_roles')
                ->select(array('role_id'))
                ->where('user_id', '=', $userid)
                ->get();

        $user = User::find($userid);
        $roles = $user->roles();

        $data = array('assigned' => $assigned, 'roles' => $roles);
        return Response::json($data);
    }
```

Returns the following (inspected using Fiddler):

```
{"assigned":[{"role_id":"2"},{"role_id":"3"},{"role_id":"4"}],"roles":{}}
```

The SQL statement that uses Query Builder returns the correct results, but the method that uses Entrust (copied from [Entrust Issue 34](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/34), after making the change to my User model) doesn't return any roles.

I also tried the solution in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958288/laravel-how-to-get-entrust-roles-of-a-specific-user), but it just gives my an SQL error.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong, I'm on Laravel 4.2.11?

My User model:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{
use HasRole;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'Users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('Password');

protected $primaryKey = 'UserID';

public $timestamps = false;

/*Standard methods removed for brevity*/

public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Role');
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like the relationship between the User model and it's roles is setup in a way that is it not working for you. Can you append the used relationship methods or traits? Thanks!

Comment: @hannesvdvreken - I've added the relevant bits of my User model

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a `roles` method defined that should not be defined. The use of the Trait `HasRole` already adds the `roles` relationship to the `User` model.

Take a look at the other stuff that the `HasRole` adds to your model: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/HasRole.php

The roles() method returns a relationship. It is recommended to return `->roles` or `->roles()->get()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: With or without my own roles method - it doesn't return anything. I've also tried renaming it to avoid a potential naming conflict, but no joy.

Comment: @SteB Try removing the () off $roles = $user->roles(); as this will return a Query builder object not the collection you are expecting, as Eloquent normally allows you to requery the relation if you use the (). But do what hannesvdvreken says.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer with more information.

Comment: @MattBurrow - If I remove the () from  $user->roles(); then I get a "Failed calling <path>\\Collection::jsonSerialize() in JsonResponse.php line 50"

Comment: As recommended by @hannesvdvreken try adding the ->get() like so; $user->roles()->get()

Comment: No closer I'm afraid, I'm beginning to suspect I'm missing something critical for the model relationships to work. I might just query the assigned_roles table directly.

Comment: This trait is deprecated